# Codeigniter update_batch--view, but not execute

Tags: codeigniter

I am using Codeigniter 3.x and want to see an update_batch query, but not run it, while I am debugging the code.

This works for an update_batch:

```
$this->db->update_batch("`" . $this->fullGamesTable . "`", $fullGames, 'gameid');
```

and updates the database, but I want to view the update and not actually do the update.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Can you do like this

```
$data = array(
array(
    'opt_id' => $hoptid1,
    'q_id' => $hid,
    'opt_val' => $sin_yes,
    'opt_crct' => $sin_yescrt,
    'opt_mark' => '1'
),
array(
    'opt_id' => $hoptid2,
    'q_id' => $hid,
    'opt_val' => $sin_no,
    'opt_crct' => $sin_nocrt,
    'opt_mark' => '1'
)
);

$this->db->update_batch('option', $data, 'opt_id');
```

Comment: I don't think that answers my question.  I want to view but not run the update.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
public function update_batch()
  { 
    $data = $this->db->select('id,description')->from('insert_batch')->group_by('url')->get()->result_array();
    $batch_update = [];
    foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
      $value['description'] = 'description';
      $batch_update[] = [
                        'id' =>$value['id'],
                        'description' => $value['description']
                        ];
    }
    echo "<pre>"; print_r($batch_update);
    $this->db->update_batch('insert_batch',$batch_update,'id');
  }
```